# Angular Notification Component with Different routerLinks not redirecting as per input

Tags: angular, typescript

I need some guidance please. I make use of a little component for showing notifications. In this component I have a routerLink, button text, and show button @Input for two buttons. In another component I assign values to these two button, and **would like to have different routes redirecting the user as per my router values.**

I am getting an issue where the secondaryRouterLink does not always fire, or it navigates to the routerLink instead of secondaryRouterLink. Sometimes it works just fine.

**Below is my Notification Component:**

```
  export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() notificationHeader = null;
  @Input() notificationMessage = null;
  @Input() buttonText = null;
  @Input() routerLink = null;
  @Input() showButton = true;

  @Input() secondaryButtonText = null;
  @Input() showSecondaryButton = false;
  @Input() secondaryRouterLink = null;

  @Input() showNotification: boolean = false;

  showNotificationMessage = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routerLink = this.router.url;
  }

  emmitEvent() {
    this.close();
    this.callParentmethod.emit();
    this.router.navigate(['/search']);
  }

  close() {
    // Default stay on current page when closing error pop-up
    this.routerLink = this.router.url;

    this.showNotificationMessage.next(false);
  }
}
```

**This is my Notification View:**

```
<div class="overlay" *ngIf="showNotification">
  <div class="box">
    <span class="fs-30 notification-header">{{ notificationHeader }}</span>
    <hr />
    <p class="notification-message">{{ notificationMessage }}</p>
    <div class="">
      <button
      *ngIf="showButton"
        type="button"
        class="af-button mt-2 mb-2 float-right mr-3"
        [routerLink]="[routerLink]"
        (click)="close()"
      >
        {{ buttonText }}
      </button>
      <button
        *ngIf="showSecondaryButton"
        type="button"
        class="af-button mt-2 mb-2 float-right mr-3"
        [routerLink]="[secondaryRouterLink]"
        (click)="close()"
      >
        {{ secondaryButtonText }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is a typical use case where I would assign values to the Notification Component:**

```
    this.showSecondaryButton = true;
    this.secondaryRouterLink = '/claims-tracking';
    this.secondaryButtonText = 'Track Claim';

    this.routerLink = '/search';
    this.buttonText = 'Close';

    this.showNotification = true;
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to make this work!

Comment: Instead of having routerLink on buttons you can move navigation logic in close method. 
close(url) {this.router.navigate([url]); ....};

Comment: Yeah it is something I am looking at. Hoping I can still make the component work :)